# I am trying to sql query by joining 2 tables by employee ID that takes the balance period between 2-12 and sums hrs and grs mtd

Tags: sql

```
SELECT I.EMPLID, 
       I.NAME, 
       I.CAG_COMPANY_DESCR, 
       I.LOCATION_NAME, 
       I.JOBCODE, 
       I.WORKERS_COMP_CD, 
       J.ERNCD, 
       J.BALANCE_QTR, 
       J.BALANCE_PERIOD, 
       J.HRS_MTD, 
       J.GRS_MTD      
FROM PS_CAG_EMPLOYEES I, PS_EARNINGS_BAL J 
WHERE J.EMPLID = I.EMPLID 
  AND J.ERNCD = '103' 
  AND J.BALANCE_YEAR = '2016' 
  AND J.BALANCE_ID = 'CY' 
  AND J.BALANCE_PERIOD ='12'
```

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Promote the use of  explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

Comment: Minus one for trying to cram your entire question into the title and not putting your question in the text of the actual question.

Comment: mysql and ms sql server are two different products. Which one do you use? What's wrong with the query?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking something like this?

```
SELECT I.EMPLID, 
       I.NAME, 
       I.CAG_COMPANY_DESCR, 
       I.LOCATION_NAME, 
       I.JOBCODE, 
       I.WORKERS_COMP_CD, 
       J.ERNCD, 
       J.BALANCE_QTR, 
       J.BALANCE_PERIOD, 
       HRS_MTD = SUM(J.HRS_MTD), 
       GRS_MTD = SUM(J.GRS_MTD)      
FROM PS_CAG_EMPLOYEES I
INNER JOIN PS_EARNINGS_BAL J 
ON J.EMPLID = I.EMPLID 
  AND J.ERNCD = '103' 
  AND J.BALANCE_YEAR = '2016' 
  AND J.BALANCE_ID = 'CY' 
  AND J.BALANCE_PERIOD ='12' 
GROUP BY 
    I.EMPLID, 
    I.NAME, 
    I.CAG_COMPANY_DESCR, 
    I.LOCATION_NAME, 
    I.JOBCODE, 
    I.WORKERS_COMP_CD, 
    J.ERNCD, 
    J.BALANCE_QTR, 
    J.BALANCE_PERIOD
```